# 'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an intern project about a college app, while running this part of the app suddenly get close. this is the part where I can upload the photos to the gallery. I am not getting any error but here  startActivityForResult(pickImage,REQ); it is saying like 'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated as a warning.

```
private String category;
private final int REQ= 1;
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image);
    selectImage = findViewById(R.id.addGalleryImage);
    imageCategory = findViewById(R.id.image_category);
    uploadImage = findViewById(R.id.uploadImageBtn);
    galleryImageView = findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);

    String[] items = new String[]{"Select Category", "Convovation", "INdependence Day","Other Events"};
    imageCategory.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items));


    imageCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            category = imageCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    });
    selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
private void openGallery(){
    Intent pickImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickImage,REQ);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        galleryImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If it is not throwing any error then what's the problem? A method is deprecated suggests that the method got a better alternative to it in recent years and the IDE is just letting you know about it.

Comment: In this case, the better alternative is `requestActivity()`, I think.

Comment: If an activity is suddenly closing on you, I suggest you put sysout or simple toast statements just before calling the activity, within the activity, and just after the activity to see where the flow is breaking.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pick image from the device then go for a newer alternative of startActiityForResult(), it's - ActivityResultLauncher

Just follow these steps :-

1. First create the ActivityResultLauncher like this :

   ```
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new 
    GetContent(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
    });
   ```
2. Then, launch system image picker on button click or however you want.

   ```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle) {

    Button selectButton = findViewById(R.id.select_button);

    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Pass in the mime type you'd like to allow the user to select
        // as the input
        mGetContent.launch("image/*");
        }
    });
   }
   ```

As you can see, you are not seeing the REQUEST_CODE anywhere. So with ActivityResultLauncher, you don't have to worry about checking different requestcodes for different tasks. ActivityResultLauncher gives you the final result if everything is ok.

You can find more about it here :- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer on google official website.
If you need requestCode todo something , just put the requestCode into the intent.
Good luck!

```java
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = result.getData();
            // Handle the Intent
        }
    }
});

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    // ...

    Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // The launcher with the Intent you want to start
            mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(this, ResultProducingActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does the line `result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK` do?